# How to merge JPA entity structure on a POST/PUT RESTful webapp

Tags: json, rest, jaxb, jax-rs, resteasy

I am starting to implement a REST layer to an existing JSF-webapp (using RESTEasy, with a Jettison provider). Since tutorials for Java REST layers are quite basic (simple objects) I am facing the question how existing JPA entity relations can be easily exposed to/consumed from the client. A simple "/user" REST-method already gives me successfully the output below, which is a good start. But my main question is - how to deal with this kind of structures. Is it common to use such structures through REST?

1. I don't want to expose all details or the whole entity-tree, wether it is because of irrelevance, saving traffic or security issues. Using @XmlTransient works fine for the @Procudes, but merging these entities on a @POST/@PUT all @XmlTransient properties are merged to NULL. What is right way of doing that?
2. Since @XMLTransient is a global and permanent setting - what is the right approach to dynamically decide which depth of entity-tree I want to expose?

thanks

Example JSON of User-entity:

```
{
 "user": {
    "id": ..,
    "uuid": "1521ccad69ba4579bbe49e75181fefc1",
    "image": "",
    "contact": {
        "id": ..,
        "uuid": "8eb429dcca994834ae5c8cf07cba62a2",
        "cellphone": "",
        "city": "",
        "country": "",
        "email": "mail@foo.bar",
        "fax": "",
        "phone": 555,
        ...
    },
    "name": "...",
    "account": {
        "id": ...,
        "uuid": "80b331f9e6644449bb3600b0e5145253",
        "confirmed": true,
        "profile": {
            "id": ...,
            "uuid": "e172bdcafe2645d7975852ca5685c98c",
            "locale": "en",
            "notifyMessage": false,
            "notifyNews": true,
            "notifyTask": true,
            "timeZone": "Europe/Berlin"
        },
        "roleProfiles": {
            "id": ..,
            "uuid": "f1713758f3f2416faed3e68350f2d759",
            "active": true,
            "assemblies": [
                {
                    "id": ..,
                    "uuid": "13d72449833a4eb0b5b4f62c729ee44f",
                    "image": "",
                    "commercialRegisters": [
                        123,
                        456
                    ],
                    "contact": {
                        "id": ...,
                        "uuid": "bef3802297344e3c8c3619b6c91c345a",
                        "city": "",
                        "country": "",
                        ...
                    },

                    "thumbnail": ""
                },
                {
                   ...
                }
            ],               
        },
        "userName": "..."
    },

    "displayName": "...",
    "firstName": "Foo",
    "lastName": "Bar",
    "salutation": "",
        "title": ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi references in your Java classes should be serialized to JSON as links and not as values.
This is how Spring REST does it.
The good thing is : That way you have a kind of lazy loading
The bad thing is that the client needs additional requests to get the values of the references.

I developed a complete solution for that, but that was a hard piece of work.
The client (in javascript) creates proxies for those references and resolves them on demand.

I have a demo of that at demo.appdriver.com
In the upper right corner you see a link 'REST API' click it and you can see the REST API of a rather complex domain model.

Now you can start to click on the user interface , create, change, delete etc.
and have a look at the traffic between client and server.

Hope it helps !